# What is difference between declarations and directives in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I've been watching several tutorials on how to write proper Angular applications, but some reference Directives in a component while others reference Declarations in a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

directives is no more , it's replaced by declaration.

directives used to be component level configuration/declaration that defines the directives/component that will be used in the view of the current component.

But when NgModule came in 2.0.0 , it replaced the directives and you should declare all your directives and component in the NgModule

so if you see a tutorial that is like bellow :

```
@Component({

   directives : [SomeComponent, SomeDirectives]
})
```

You can consider that list in the `NgModule` of this component like bellow :

```
@NgModule({
   declarations:[SomeComponent, SomeDirectives]
})
```

And remove it from the component